# Git branching strategy for multiple releases

Tags: git, gitlab, branching-and-merging

My team is new to GIT (using GitLab) and we're  trying to solve the following problem.

I have Project A and it has 3 teams working on it.

Team 1 has a Jan release

Team 2 has a March release

Team 3 has a July release

We have the idea of Master for Production Code.
The question we are struggling with is what is the best way to enforce that Team 2 has all of Team 1's changes and Team 3 has all of Team 1 and 2's changes.

We have a DevJan, DevMarch,DevJuly branches. But it seems like there is no good way for the changes to flow upstream properly.

Do we just rebase periodically? Commit to all 3 branches if you are team 1 ?
I haven't found a similar scenario in all the GIT discussions.

Answer (score 1):

Because the branches in question exist specifically for collaboration purposes, I would not make rebasing them a part of your workflow.  You could make it a practice to periodically merge DevJan into DevMarch, and then merge DevMarch into DevJuly.

The downside to that workflow...  Teams 2 and 3 will be absorbing team 1's changes in periodic chunks, which may magnify merge headaches - but this is inherent to the decision to have three concurrent long-lived dev branches.  The best way to mitigate that is to make the "periodic" merges pretty frequent - maybe daily - which means you'll get a good number of merge commits bringing "earlier release" changes into the "later release" branches.  While some people don't like "extra" merge commits, if you use feature branches (and I suggest you should) then the dev branches will be nothing but a series of merge commits anyway.

Comment: An alternative that my team uses is to submit multiple PRs targeting the releases affected by the issue. It's a pain either way.

Answer (score 0):

Well. You can put them in 1 repo.

You can `git checkout -b Release/July` , commit all the sources from your current July project, then from there `git checkout -b Release/March`, commit again from March, then `git checkout -b Release/Jan`, commit. 
So you will have a structure like

```
----------- Release/July   Team 3
    \------- Release/March   Team 2 
     \-------- Release/Jan     Team 1
```

Now they can each have their merging strategies to their own release branches, 
and you can merge the branches upward, mind that while merging there can be nice conflicts here, and you need to "chain" up everything from the branches below.

`rebase` or `cherry-pick` can be better if you have parts between branches what you can't merge up (db schemes for example), and have to be strict what you have to merge up. But imho either way it's tricky to maintain multiple releases.